# Creating array of quiz questions that do not repeat

Tags: xcode, random, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to create a basic quiz app where the questions will not repeat. I've looked at several examples and believe I should be storing the questions in an array and then removing one from the array each time its used. I've tried the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//The array of questions
NSMutableArray *questionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"First Question",@"Answer A", nil],
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Second Quesiton",@"AnswerA",@"AnswerB", nil],
                                 nil];


//remove used question from array
for (int i = questionArray.count; i>=0; --i) {
    _questions = [questionArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % questionArray.count];

    [questionArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:_questions];
}

//use array object
self.lblQuestion.text = [_questions objectAtIndex:0];
[self.btnA setTitle:[_questions objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I'm getting the following warning:
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending NSMutableArray*_strong to parameter of type 'NSUInteger'

I take it this means I shouldn't be using another array to store the random question as I can't use this to remove the question from the array. However I don't know how else to do this?

Am I completely misunderstanding how I should go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal here is to get non-repeating questions...

I believe that instead of removing the question you have already used, you should SHUFFLE your array at the beginning and then loop through the array one index at a time using a simple counter.

I hope you can find this piece of code helpful -- give it a shot:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)shuffleArray:(NSMutableArray *)anArray
    NSUInteger count = [anArray count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
    {
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [anArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }

    return anArray;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //The array of questions
    NSMutableArray *questionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"First Question",@"Answer A", nil],
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Second Quesiton",@"AnswerA",@"AnswerB", nil],
                             nil];

    //Shuffle the question array -- Now all indexes are shuffled and Random
    questionArray = [self shuffleArray:questionArray];

    //Every time you want to move to the next question, all you have to do is connect a button to the nextIndex action and let it do all the work!
    //Use the nextIndex method to initialise -- we call it manually the first time so things would get going and something is displayed -- you can remove the line below if you want it to initialise on first button click! Your call the shots sir!
    [self nextIndex];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}

//Edit -- This method shows how to change question array index using a method
int currentIndex = 0;
-(IBAction)nextIndex
{
    if ( currentIndex == [questionArray count] )
    {
        currentIndex = 0; //Resets the var when getting to the final Index
        //The above line will result in a question loop -- meaning if you arrive at the last question, the next question will be the first! Pacman mode!
        //If you want to stop at the last question just change the above line to return; and you're all set!
    }

    //Set _questions object to the current Index Array element
    _questions = [questionArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex];

    //Increment currentIndex for next use
    currentIndex++;

    //use the array object to set your objects' values
    self.lblQuestion.text = [_questions objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.btnA setTitle:[_questions objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

You will end up having totally different questions that are shuffled every time.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, it seems to work. The only problem I have is that I can't get it to increment more than once (i've added more questions). I'm not sure of the correct way to move to the next index in the array. I've tried putting the following in a button but only works on first click `for (i = 0; i < [_questionArray count]; i++) {
        
        _questions = [_questionArray objectAtIndex:i];`

Comment: Hello, I've edited my answer and added a function that helps you iterate through the indexes of your array. All you need to do is add the code above and attach the action to a button and you're all set.